# Where is the Warehouse Block?

Tags: underrail

Okay.  I know I'm supposed to go see the commander or something on the commons deck as soon as possible, but on my way there I met this interesting fellow in the canteen who told me his name was *Jack Quicksilver*.

Jack turned out to be really nice, and even offered me a job!  It's only package delivery, but hey: money is money, right?  He gave me the key to a footlocker somewhere in the barracks, and asked me if I could take the package inside to a man waiting outside the *Warehouse Block*, where I would get paid.  Simple, right?

Well, I'm new in town, and one of the first things Jack asked me is if I knew where the "warehouse block" is.  Wanting to impress my new BFF, I lied and said yes, but I actually have no idea where it is.  Jack doesn't want to talk about the job any more until it's done, and now I can't even find him again; I'm sure he's working hard for the good of the community though, like everyone else!

I really don't want to mess up so soon in this place.  Anybody know where the Warehouse Block is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [wiki](http://www.underrail.com/wiki/index.php?title=GMS_warehouse_block), the GMS warehouse block is located somewhere in Lower Underrail in an area outside GMS compound.

The wiki entry for [Jack's delivery job](http://www.underrail.com/wiki/index.php?title=Jack%27s_delivery_job) states the directions to the warehouse block:

> Once you have the package, head north. As soon as you leave the station, you will encounter three bandits bend on taking the package from you. Deal with them and keep moving. Make your way to the GMS warehouse block, which is directly to the west from the intersection after the bandits. Once there, head to the southwesternmost warehouse building and talk to the man there to receive your reward.

Comment: Nice, this didn't even have a wiki back when I asked it!